# Entity Framework Core 3.1 with NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point: SqlException: The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type geography

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, geospatial, ef-core-3.1, nettopologysuite

I have a model that looks like this:

```
public class Facility
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point Location { get; set; }
}
```

Test code for adding a Point:

```
var testFacility = new Facility();
testFacility.Location = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point(13.003725d, 55.604870d) { SRID = 3857 };

//Other values tested with the same error error

//testFacility.Location = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point(13.003725d, 55.604870d);

//testFacility.Location = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point(55.604870d, 13.003725d);

//var geometryFactory = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid: 3857);
//var currentLocation = geometryFactory.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(13.003725d, 55.604870d));
//testFacility.Location = currentLocation;

db.Facilities.Add(testFacility);
//Exception on Save
db.SaveChanges();
```

I'm using the following NuGets, version `3.1.0`

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite
```

The exception I get on save is the following:

> SqlException: The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure
>   call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 7 ("@p6"): The
>   supplied value is not a valid instance of data type geography. Check
>   the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is
>   data of numeric type with scale greater than precision.

According to all documentation it should be X for longitude and Y for latitude so I don't think that is a problem. I tried to reverse the coordinates just in case but I got the same error as you can see in the examples I have tried.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial

Lat = Y Long = X

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/68856/71364

I can't find out anything obvious that seems wrong. Optionsbuilder is set up, the table is created with Data Type `geography` that worked really well with `DbGeography` for Entity Framework 6.

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());

var db = new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

There is no specific cases to handle for a single `Point` either what I can see in documentation for SQL server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial#sql-server

The coordinates I'm saving is from Google Maps and therefore `EPSG 3857` is used.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/epsg-3857-or-4326-for-googlemaps-openstreetmap-and-leaflet

What am I missing?

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that NET Topology Suite maps its `Point` class to the MSSQL `geometry` type, not `geography`. Hence when attempting to persist the record, NTS serializes a `geometry` while MSSQL expects a `geography` and everything explodes.

Comment: @IanKemp I think they might need a tuning then. ;) It was the SRID not present in SQL Server `sys.spatial_reference_systems`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**TLDR**

The SRID is not present in SQL Server `sys.spatial_reference_systems`

[image]

Change to one that exist like `4326` and it will work:

[image]

```
select *
from sys.spatial_reference_systems
where spatial_reference_id = '4326'
```

**Long answer:**

Google Maps API uses `EPSG 3857` but Google Maps Web application uses `EPSG 4326`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

https://www.google.com/maps/@55.604933,13.003662,14z

[image]

Therefore a point from Google Maps Web Application should be created and saved like this:

```
var testFacility = new Facility();
testFacility.Location = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point(13.003725d, 55.604870d) { SRID = 4326 };
db.Facilities.Add(testFacility);
db.SaveChanges();
```

It was however a bit tricky to project `EPSG 4326` coordinates to `EPSG 3857` coordinate system. Microsoft recommends using `ProjNet4GeoAPI` so I decided to use that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial#srid-ignored-during-client-operations

I have verified that it works here:

http://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=3857&x=13.003725&y=55.604870

Example conversion:

```
var x = 13.003725d;
var y = 55.604870d;

var epsg3857ProjectedCoordinateSystem = ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.ProjectedCoordinateSystem.WebMercator;
var epsg4326GeographicCoordinateSystem = ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84;

var coordinateTransformationFactory = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.CoordinateTransformationFactory();
var coordinateTransformation = coordinateTransformationFactory.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(epsg4326GeographicCoordinateSystem, epsg3857ProjectedCoordinateSystem);

var epsg4326Coordinate = new GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate(x, y);

var epsg3857Coordinate = coordinateTransformation.MathTransform.Transform(epsg4326Coordinate);
```

Complete example program:

To get it running:

- Install NuGets

  - Following NuGets are at version 3.1:

    - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
    - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
    - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
    - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite
  - ProjNET4GeoAPI
- Add-Migration InitialCreate
- Update-Database

Code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using NetTopologySuite;
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;
using ProjNet.CoordinateSystems;
using ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.Transformations;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace TestConsoleAppEFGeo
{
    public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=TestApp;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
                x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());

            return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Facility> Facilities { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    public class Facility
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point Location { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var applicationDbContextFactory = new ApplicationDbContextFactory();
            var db = applicationDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(null);

            var x = 13.003725d;
            var y = 55.604870d;
            var srid = 4326;

            if (!db.Facilities.AnyAsync(x => x.Id == 1).Result)
            {
                var testFacility = new Facility();
                var geometryFactory = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid);
                var currentLocation = geometryFactory.CreatePoint(new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate(x, y));
                testFacility.Id = 1;
                testFacility.Location = currentLocation;

                var testFacility2 = new Facility();
                testFacility2.Id = 2;
                testFacility2.Location = new Point(x, y) { SRID = srid };
                db.Facilities.Add(testFacility);
                db.Facilities.Add(testFacility2);

                //Will throw an exception
                //var testFacility3 = new Facility();
                //testFacility3.Id = 3;
                //testFacility3.Location = new Point(1447568.0454157612d, 7480155.2276327936d) { SRID = 3857 };
                //db.Facilities.Add(testFacility3);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            var facility1 = db.Facilities.FirstAsync(x => x.Id == 1).Result;
            var facility2 = db.Facilities.FirstAsync(x => x.Id == 2).Result;

            if(facility1.Location == facility2.Location)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("facility1.Location is equal to facility2.Location");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("facility1.Location is NOT equal to facility2.Location");
            }

            //Test conversion
            //Show coordinate: http://epsg.io/map#srs=4326&x=13.003725&y=55.604870&z=14&layer=streets
            //Conversion: http://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=3857&x=13.0037250&y=55.6048700
            //Google Maps - https://www.google.se/maps shows EPSG:4326 when viewing a location
            //https://epsg.io/3857 - Google Maps API is EPSG:3857 however
            //Example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

            var epsg3857ProjectedCoordinateSystem = ProjectedCoordinateSystem.WebMercator;
            var epsg4326GeographicCoordinateSystem = GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84;

            var coordinateTransformationFactory = new CoordinateTransformationFactory();
            var coordinateTransformation = coordinateTransformationFactory.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(epsg4326GeographicCoordinateSystem, epsg3857ProjectedCoordinateSystem);

            var epsg4326Coordinate = new GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate(facility1.Location.Coordinate.X, facility1.Location.Coordinate.Y);

            var epsg3857Coordinate = coordinateTransformation.MathTransform.Transform(epsg4326Coordinate);

        }
    }
}
```

More info here:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19416

Comment: Why can't the fix be something like: INSERT INTO sys.spatial_reference_systems (spatial_reference_id, authority_name, authorized_spatial_reference_id, well_known_text, unit_of_measure, unit_conversion_factor)
VALUES (3857, 'EPSG', 3857, 'GEOGCS["idk"]', 'radian', 1)?

Answer (score 0):

[It's probably already in 4326](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/380296/173152), happy days, easy to store, sql should let you store this (an API might use `3857` but supply a location's lat/lon in degrees not metres and actually you've already been given the lat/lon in `4326`)

---

Assuming you are getting lat/lon's in `SRID=3857` and want to try to store it that way:

Check you have a version of an SRID equivalent to `3857` that'll work in your DB

```
SELECT * FROM sys.spatial_reference_systems 
WHERE authorized_spatial_reference_id 
IN('3857', '900913', '3587', '54004', '41001', '102113', '102100', '3785')
```

For example if you happen to have [900913](https://epsg.io/900913) try using that on a lat/lon insert with no conversion if you have it, I'm basing this assumption on comparing the properties of the hyperlinked "alternatives codes" to [EPSG:3857](https://epsg.io/3857)

I have no idea if it'll work, and this is totally not my field of knowledge.

Assuming you get no SQL rows back then you'll have to convert `3857` to `4326` to store in your DB...

---

How to convert `3857` to `4326` so you can store it:

Install ProjNet4GeoAPI via NuGet and use the following code:

```
using GeoAPI.Geometries;
using ProjNet.CoordinateSystems;
using ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.Transformations;
```

...

```
// setup
var epsg3857 = ProjectedCoordinateSystem.WebMercator;
var epsg4326 = GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84;
var convertTo4326 = new CoordinateTransformationFactory()
                        .CreateFromCoordinateSystems(epsg3857, epsg4326);

// input 6415816.17/171048.38 (Brussels lat/lon in meters SRID 3857)
//       N.B. method called needs the values as lon/lat (x/y), not lat/lon 
var coordIn3857 = new GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate(171048.38, 6415816.17);

var coordIn4326 = convertTo4326.MathTransform.Transform(coordIn3857);
// output 49.82379612579344/1.5365537407788388 (Brussels lat/lon in degrees SRID 4326)
```

now go save that into your DB

```
testFacility.Location = new NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point(1.536553, 49.823796) 
                             { SRID = 4326 };
```

To convert in the other direction and use `3857` from stored `4326` values, it's pretty easy to figure out or see Ogglas's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59667168/1452172)